# How to make the brackets surrounding tuple elements of a list disappear in stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, python-itertools

I've written the following code:

```
from itertools import product

list_A = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
list_B = [int(y) for y in input().split()]

print(list(product(list_A, list_B)))
```

**Sample Input**

```
1 2
3 4
```

**Code Output**

```
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

How can I make the two brackets disappear and rather get `(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)` as output?

Comment: Unpack it with star `print(*list(product(list_A, list_B)))`

Comment: @ChrisCharley Wow, cool! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

essentially you are asking how to print a list but remove the brackets on the two ends:

```
l = [(1,2), (3,4)]

print(', '.join(map(str, l)))
```

output:

```
(1, 2), (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```py
print(str(list(product(list_A, list_B)))[1:-1])
```

Comment: I like your solution!